Setting a max-width on a component
I'm creating a chat-app where I want the messages to have a max-width of lets say 50% of screen size, but I'm not sure how to get it to work ...
return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        borderRadius: chatBorder,
        color: chatColor,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      messageSender,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        fontSize: 10.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                    child: Text(
                      timeNow,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white70,
                        fontSize: 10.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  messageText,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 15.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );


Following is what my app looks like now but i want it to only take 50% of the screen width / message and reduce the unnecessary blank space.

Have you tried wrapping this in a FractionallySizedBox that forces the widthFactor to 0.5 ?

You may wrap the Row widget with a "SizedBox" having width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.50. This should set the row size with 50% of the viewport width. If you wish to apply it before applying the Padding then use this as top level widget.

Thanks @RandalSchwartz, wrapping the whole thing with a FractionallySizedBox did the job!

You can wrap widget with ConstrainedBox for set maxWidth

Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
  child: Material(
    elevation: 5.0,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13.0),
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
        child: const Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    'messageSender',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontSize: 10.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                  child: Text(
                    'timeNow',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontSize: 10.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'messageText',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),


FractionallySizedBox is closer to the OP's original request.

@RandalSchwartz yes FractionallySizedBox work as well but I which one is most correct answer it depend on OP propose because ConstrainedBox can set max width with real screen width but FractionallySizedBox it pretty similar to ConstrainedBox . the different is FractionallySizedBox width is  screen width - padding

and i think i was chat message so it possible to have shorter message and it gonna look weird if message box always took half of the screen width even for short message so i think ConstrainedBox is good option because we can set minWidth for message box too
